# Shorthand for isset and !empty

Tags: php, variables, null

Stupid question, I know, but if I don't know whether a variable `$var` is set or not, should I use

```
isset($var) && !empty($var)
```

to check if it has any value in it, or is

`!empty($var)` enough? Would there be a problem if `$var` is null in the second case?

Comment: Why not just check the php manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: With that criteria there wouldn't be any questions in StackOverflow, right?

Comment: Krister has a point. The manual states `empty() is the opposite of (boolean) var, except that no warning is generated when the variable is not set.` You could conclude from this that it's ok to *not* use `isset()`. I'm not against your question though, as others may not make that connection.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it was so explicit in the manual. I thought only on certain occasions the use of empty was enough. Anyways, thanks for the answers to everybody!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`isset`](http://php.net/isset) and [`empty`](http://php.net/empty) are both language constructs. And `empty()` internally does an `isset` check first, then negates that, or alternatively also checks for values that equate `FALSE` in boolean context.

So yes, `!empty()` is sufficient.

Comment: Incorret, if $var is set to 0, then it IS set, but it is considered empty.

Comment: @kylex. mario is correct specifically because the op is also checking if the variable is not empty. If he were only wanting to know if the variable was set, then yes, he should use isset().

Comment: Let `$a=0;` then `var_dump(isset($a) && !empty($a));` and `var_dump(!empty($a));` will both say `false`. Same for undefined vars.

Comment: Are we considering 0 a non-value then? It's difficult to tell by the question.

Comment: The crux is the negation here. `empty` would consider `0` falsy. But since it queries `!empty` it wouldn't matter.

Comment: @mario, I think you have it backwards. empty would consider 0 TRUE, since 0 IS empty, when negated it becomes false. If `empty(0) === true` but `!empty(0) === false`.

Comment: @kylex: Well, yes. `empty` is equivalent to the boolean typecast `(bool)$var` (except that it also probes for existence in the local varscope). `0` is a *falsy* value, hence the `empty()` check returns `true`. -- OPs question was all about testing whether there is a **non-falsy** value, not if the variable is just set. And that's what `empty()` does. Not sure where you were going otherwise the `0` example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can drop the [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset):

> `empty()` is the opposite of `(boolean) var`, except that **no warning is generated when the variable is not set**.

You can see this with the following code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

var_dump(empty($var));
```

```
bool(true)
```

(Note the lack of an undefined variable warning)

Answer (score 2):

You should use isset(), as !empty() will return false if your $var is 0.

```
<?php
$var = 0;

// Evaluates to true because $var is empty
if (empty($var)) {
    echo '$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
}

//Evaluates false because $var is empty
if(!empty($var)){

}

// Evaluates as true because $var is set
if (isset($var)) {
    echo '$var is set even though it is empty';
}
?>
```

Comment: @tandu: Yes, it will. 0 is considered empty, it's stated in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 1):

I think you can drop that `isset()` completely in case you're using `empty()`, because `empty()` checks whether variable is set first, too

so after all, use

```
if (!empty($var)) {
    //isset and not empty
}
```